# How do I automatically put categories and their descriptions on a WP Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am using a blog to keep track of citations I may want to use for a thesis. Each citation is a Post, authors are categories, which are parents to subcategories that are named for the titles of books or articles by that author. In the description of the book/article subcategories, I put the publishing information, e.g. “Penguin: London, 2007”.

Let’s assume that a particular author category is called “Mill, John Stuart” (for whom there are four citations), the book subcategory “On Liberty” (for which there are two citations), and the description “Bantam Classic: London, 1993”. Now, I would like to add a Page that shows all the sources that I have gathered, automatically outputting HTML code like this:

```
<p class="lit-author"><a href="../category/mill-john-stuart/">Mill, John Stuart</a> (4)</p>
<p class="lit-work"><a href="../category/mill-john-stuart/on-liberty/"><i>On Liberty<i></a>. Bantam Classic: London, 1993. (2)</p>
```

This might just as well be done with <ul>s, I’m really only interested in being able to format the output using CSS and having in on a Page. (It’s pretty much just the contents of a Categories widget plus the category description, but on a Page.)

How would I do this, and where would I have to put the relevant code so that it would be displayed on a specific Page?

(WP 3.2.1, Graphene 1.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of category.php and name it **category-slug.php** where "slug" is the category slug set in the wordpress admin. This way, you can customize the page for each specific category. WordPress will display posts for that category when you visit the page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Now, in reference to the title of your question "*How do I automatically put categories and their descriptions on a WP Page?*" To display a category description on a page, you can use the following code:

```
<?php 

//store the category id by the slug for any page
$cat_id = get_category_by_slug('slug')->term_id

//displays the category name
echo get_cat_name( $cat_id );

//displays the category description
echo category_description( $cat_id  ); 

?>
```